# How to limit text in textfield when entered text through speech

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I am having 3 textfields and I have restricted character limit to 50 for each textfield using UITextFeildDelegate method and it is working fine. Now when I try to input text through speech and not by keyboard then the textfield seems to accept more than 50 characters and some time the whole text disappear when the speech input is completed.

Here is my delegate method `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`

```
if(textField==self.optionATextField || textField==self.optionBTextField ||textField==self.optionCTextField) {
    if(range.length + range.location > textField.text.length) {
        return NO;
    }
    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return newLength <= 50;
}
```

Is there any way to do it? Do I need to implement any other method for speech input to work properly.

Hope you understand the problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you wanting the text field to be truncated at 50 characters if the entered text would become longer than 50? BTW - do you have same need if the user pastes text in as well as using speech?

Comment: @rmaddy I want to limit the text entry when 50 characters reached... not truncated, for both pasting and speech

Comment: Lets say there are 40 characters and the user pastes 20 more. Do you want to ignore the whole 20 or let the first 10 through making it 50?

Comment: I want first 10 to make it 50

Comment: OK, that's what my answer does.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you want the entered text to be truncated to a maximum of 50 characters regardless of the method of entry, you can do something like this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if(textField==self.optionATextField || textField==self.optionBTextField ||textField==self.optionCTextField) {
        NSString *newText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
        if (newText.length < 50) {
            // Text length is still OK, let it through
            return YES;
        } else {
            // The new text is too long - truncate and set the shorter value
            newText = [newText substringToIndex:50];
            textField.text = newText;

            return NO;
        }
    } else {
        return YES; // do whatever you need here
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the code...but it seems to accept more than 50 characters while inputting through speech.

Comment: Is the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` called when inputting through speech? Set a break point and see what happens.

Comment: 'shouldChangeCharactersInRange` is only called when done button is clicked and not when entering the text through speech.

Comment: I just did a test in my app. While using dictation, the text appears to be entered as you speak. The `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` will be called when you tap Done. At that point the text will be truncated. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, the code in my answer. After you tap Done, the text will be truncated to 50 characters.

Comment: Is there any method to limit that entry to 50 and not enter any character after that?

Comment: Yes, the code in answer. Why do you keep asking this over and over? I'm confused. Type text, truncated at 50. Paste text, truncate at 50. Dictate text. Dictated text (all of it) will appear. After tapping done, it will be truncated at 50. Why do you keep asking how to limit to 50 when that is what this does? Please clarify.

Comment: What I meant was that instead of allowing all text to be entered through dictation is it possible to stop entering text when 50 character reached? Just like when we type through keyboard, no text will be added if character limit reach 50. hope you understand

Comment: OK, dictation definitely works differently. The text appears in the text field but the value of the text field isn't actually set until Done is tapped. So there doesn't appear to be a way since no delegate methods are called until Done is tapped.

Answer (score 1):

shouldChangeCharactersInRange , override method won't be called when user is using dictation(Speech To Text) function.
What you can do is,(This example is on C#(Xamarin iOS))

1.Use :

```
textField.EditingChanged += textField_EditingChanged;
```

2.Inside the below method implement following, 
maxLength: Max length for searchBar textfield

```
private void textField_EditingChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var textField = sender as UITextField;
   var maxLengthSubstractionValue = textField.Text.Length.CompareTo(maxLength);
      if(maxLengthSubstractionValue == 1)
         {
           textField.Text =  textField.Text.Substring(0, Math.Min(maxLength, textField.Text.Length));
         }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement the functionality, you have to use `textViewDidChange` delegate method.

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView { 
    if (textView.text.length > kMaxCharAllowed) {
        textView.text = [textView.text substringToIndex:kMaxCharAllowed];
    }
}
```

This method will be called whenever there is a change in text field string. We replace the text with a string of the desired length if the text is lengthier than desired.

Along with this, use `- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text` method to handle the keyboard inputs.